# Loop Python Script with Alternating Variable Value

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering if anyone had experience with looping a Python script in Jupyter Notebook that alternates the variable value through each iteration of the loop?

The example below will summarize what I'm looking for:

variable_file = [file_1, file_2, file_3, etc....]

Around 20 cells which reference variable_file

Final output cell which spits back the desired result for the first file.

After this final output cell, I would like to rerun the entire script but with file_2, etc...until all files in the variable_file list have been run.

If anyone was any input or tips, it would be greatly appreciated!

I tried some if statements, but this problem is way out of the realm of my expertise and I'm far more comfortable with R than Python.

Comment: Is your first pass with file_1 done the way it is so you can show in detail what is happening as it goes along and then for the additional ones you just want to run everything 'straight away'. If so, then in addition to glicerico's excellent suggestion to encapsulate in a function, I'd suggest then you bindle everything in a separate script that you run in your notebook with each new one as a setting. If you use `%run -i` to call your script, it will run in the namespace of the notebook at the time. So you could sill use glicero's `for var in variable_file:` line, but call the script..

Comment: Note that the scripts can use IPython magic if you end them with `.ipy` as opposed to `.py` like a pure Python script. Some where that will give you an idea of what I mean, although I don't process the first one separate like you seem to want, is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/bendit-binder/tree/master). Click `launch binder` at the top there & when the session starts up, do a `Run All`. You'll see it will process two sequence strings in `demo_sample_set.fa`. If there had been other `.fa` files there it would use them too. (I developed that with the script as `.ipy` initially.)

Comment: An even more complex way would be to think of each notebook as a report and make a new notebook for each file. That may no quite suit what you want here but parameterizing notebooks can be done. One way is to use [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). You can imagine having a control notebook that is spawning notebooks processing each of your files. I do something like that if you go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/pdbsum-binder) and click `launch binder` and then pick 'Using snakemake to highlight changes in multiple protein-protein interactions via PDBsum data' under ...

Comment: <continued> available notebooks. I control the notebook making in a more granular way than with papermill but the idea is the same. I just built the 'template' notebook into the code and not as a separate `.ipynb` file. And I don't use papermill at all. Instead I make the notebooks and execute them with jupytext. The [Snakefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fomightez/pdbsum-binder/main/notebooks/Snakefile) that makes and runs them is really a glorified Python script as Snakemake and Snakefiles are a supserset of Python. In other words, I could have just used Python to do that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the "around 20 cells" inside the loop. The loop has to be contained in a single cell.
If you really want the content of each cell to be in a separate cell, you can create a function in each cell by encapsulating its content.

Example:

In cell 1:

```
def cell_1(var):
  <do something using var>
```

In cell 2:

```
def cell_2(var):
  <do something else>
```

In the final cell:

```
variable_file = [file_1, file_2, file_3]
for var in variable_file:
  cell_1(var)
  cell_2(var)
  ...
```